# Nested If Conditions in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hello i have the following store procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE update_stock_level
(
    @ItemID int,
    @Quantity int = 1,
    @Return int = 0
)
AS

    IF @Return = 0
        UPDATE  Stock
        SET     Quantity    = (Quantity - @Quantity)
        WHERE   ItemID      =   @ItemID

    ELSE 
        UPDATE  Stock
        SET     Quantity    = (Quantity + @Quantity)
        WHERE   ItemID      =   @ItemID
```

This stored procedure is for A POS application, what this procedure does(should do) is update(increase or decrease) the stock level based on the item id and the item's quantity.

ItemID -> ID of item selected from front end.
Quantity -> How many items
Return -> If return is '0' that means it is false, meaning this is not a return sale if it is '1' it means an item is being returned in which case the stock should increase by the quantity returned.  If nothing is passed to the qantity parameter then the default is 1.

My issue now is that the stock level get's reduced fine but it does not increase when a return is made.

Comment: If @quantity =0 .. set Quantity= Quantity - @Quantity?

Comment: Oh thank you i dunno it wasn't that way before i must have done something. :)

Comment: As @Stoleg said, your first condition if quantity = 0 will have no effect. And you're doing exactly the same if quantity = 0 or else !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave just `ELSE` part:

```
IF @Return = 0
    UPDATE  Stock
    SET     Quantity    = (Quantity - @Quantity)
    WHERE   ItemID      =   @ItemID
ELSE 
    UPDATE  Stock
    SET     Quantity    = (Quantity + @Quantity)
    WHERE   ItemID      =   @ItemID
```

Alternatively you can do it in a single statemnet:

```
UPDATE  Stock
SET     Quantity    = Quantity - @Quantity * POWER(-1,@Return)
WHERE   ItemID      = @ItemID
```

If @Return=0 then power(-1,0) = 1 and you decrease stock.

If @Return=1 then power(-1,1) = -1 and you increase stock.

Comment: Updated my code, however stock level only decreases but does not increase when a return is made.

Comment: Does it decrease for any value of @Return?

Comment: Thanks your actually worked, the reason why it wasn't updating was because i had to change some stuff at the front end.